# probability of getting 3 hearts given another deck got 4 hearts.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability, card-games

from a standard pack of 52 cards, you and your friend are getting 7 cards each, given the fact that you have 4 hearts, whats the probability that your friend has 3 hearts.

at first i marked the event $A$ as the event of you get 4 hearts and the event $B$ of your friend getting 3 hearts. so we are looking for $\mathbb{P}[B|A]$.

so from the formula of conditional probability we need $\mathbb{P}[B\cap A]$ and $\mathbb{P}[A]$

$\mathbb{P}[A]$ we can get by: $$\frac{\binom{13}{4}}{\binom{52}{7}}$$
but when im trying to find $\mathbb{P}[B\cap A]$ im running to troubles.

Comment: For a *much* simpler way of understanding the problem... compare to the question of the probability of pulling $3$ red balls out of a bag of $(52-7)$ balls where $(13-4)$ of which are red.

Comment: As to your attempt and your approach, your probability for $\Pr(A)$ is incorrect.  It should have been $\dfrac{\binom{13}{4}\binom{39}{3}}{\binom{52}{7}}$, and the probability $\Pr(B\cap A)$ you could have continued in exactly the same way to find as $\dfrac{\binom{13}{4}\binom{39}{3}\binom{9}{3}\binom{36}{4}}{\binom{52}{7}\binom{45}{7}}$... but as alluded to previously this is entirely too much effort for a problem like this.  Just use the intuitive meaning of conditional probability.

Comment: i get why my approach is wrong but can you explain the $Pr(A)$ that you got?

Comment: A hand of seven cards with four hearts specifically contains four of the available hearts *and three of the available non-heart cards*.  If the non-heart cards were to change then the hand changes too.